# VS Code console.log() appears in developer tools instead of debug console

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I've been working on a VS Code extension using the Hello World example generated by Yeoman (`yo code`). The `console.log()` message only shows up in the Developer Tools, but *not* in the Debug Console like all of the VS Code documentation suggests. Here is my `launch.json` (it is unchanged from what `yo code` generated:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}",
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test/suite/index"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/test/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried adding `"console": "internalConsole"`, `"debugOptions": ["RedirectOutput"]`, and `"outputCapture": "std"` as suggested in various other answers on Stack Overflow, but A) none of those work and B) they give an error in `launch.json` that `Property <property> is not allowed`.

I'm launching using `F5` (run *with* debugging). Breakpoints do work, logpoints *don't* log anything to Debug Console either.

What am I missing?

Comment: I wonder which "Debug Console" you checked. You should check the "Debug Console" of the initial VSCode instance, not of the instance being debugged.

Comment: Make your debugged VSC window a bit smaller so you can see the Debug console of the VSC window that contains the extension source code

Comment: Just to be sure, I have checked the Debug Console in both windows to no avail...